# Cassandra Vs Dynamo database primary keys selection

Tags: cassandra, amazon-dynamodb

I have used cassandra in past where it was advisable to keep data related to key on single node.

Today I was studying dynamo database documentation and in this it was suggested to segregate data across multiple nodes for a key to avoid hot partitioning & R/W throughput.

I might be wrong also so can anyone explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with dynamo, I do know that Cassandra has had problems with hot partitioning too. [Vnodes were released in 1.2](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2) to help with this.

`Bucketing` is another concept commonly used in Cassandra data modelling. See [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusHfer/bucket-your-partitions-wisely-cassandra-summit-2016) from Cassandra summit 2016.